# Problem with Influxdb2/grafana on docker, can't access influx bash commands nor can't connect to the database from grafana

Tags: docker, grafana, influxdb

i'm currently trying to setup a grafana/influxdb2 interaction for IoT purposes.
Both are running insides dockers and they are equally reachable via host machine browser on the respective port

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 `
    --name=grafana `
    -v ${PWD}:/var/lib/grafana `
    -e "GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=test" `
    -e "GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=grafana-clock-panel,grafana-simple-json-datasource" `
    -e "GF_SECURITY_ALLOW_EMBEDDING=true" `
    -e "GF_USERS_ALLOW_SIGN_UP=false" `
    -e "GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ENABLED=true" `
    -e "GF_AUTH_BASIC_ENABLED=false" `
    -e "GF_SERVER_PROTOCOL=https" `
    -e "GF_SERVER_CERT_FILE=/var/lib/grafana/ssl/grafana.crt" `
    -e "GF_SERVER_CERT_KEY=/var/lib/grafana/ssl/grafana.key" `
    grafana/grafana

docker run -d -p 8086:8086 `
    --name=influxdb2 `
    -v ${PWD}/influxdb2:/var/lib/influxdb2 `
    -e DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_MODE=setup `
    -e DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_USERNAME=admin`
    -e DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PASSWORD=test`
    -e DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ORG=my `
    -e DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_BUCKET=PVdb `
    -e INFLUXDB_HTTP_HTTPS_ENABLED=true `
    -e INFLUXDB_HTTP_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE=/var/lib/ssl/influxdb2.crt`
    -e INFLUXDB_HTTP_HTTPS_PRIVATE_KEY=/var/lib/ssl/influxdb2.key `
    influxdb:2.0
```

I'll start listing the issues im facing:

1. Influxdb is not running under HTTPS even though i'm passing those -e commands, i guess i'm missing something for sure since the docker log isn't reporting anything. --> Solved, see below
2. I browsed through a lot of videos and all the tutorials are showing how you can do

```
docker exec -it influxdb2 sh
```

and then

```
influx
show database
```

to see the current status but in my case when i type "influx" i'm instead receiving

```
Influx Client

Usage:
  influx [command]

Available Commands:
...
```

and "show" is not recognized as command.
--> See below

3. What i'm currently missing is a "basic" way to write/read to get confident with the tool
4. I've also tried using POST commands

```
curl --request POST "http://localhost:8086/api/v2/write?org=my&bucket=PVdb&precision=s" --header "Authorization: Token myTOKEN" --data-raw "mem,host=host1 used_percent=23.43234543 1556896326"
```

but curl is not returning anything and i have yet no way to check if the data is present.

5. As last issue in grafana when i add the influxdb (Query Language Flux, URL: http://localhost:8086 (Server)) with Organization, Token and Bucket by pressing Save & Test i receive

```
Error reading InfluxDB
```

--> Solved, see below

Answer:

1. Add this (even though http is still available)

```
-e INFLUXD_TLS_CERT=/var/lib/influxdb2/ssl/influxdb2.crt `
-e INFLUXD_TLS_KEY=/var/lib/influxdb2/ssl/influxdb2.key `
```

2. I guess all the tutorials are about influxdb 1.8, now the client uses

```
influx query
```

altough you can try and use

```
influx v1 dbrp
```

5. I had to change "localhost" with the "machine local ip" in the URL (e.g. https://192.x.x.x:8086)

Regards

Comment: Regarding machine IP, `http://influxdb:8086` should work, assuming influxdb is the name of the service (which is different of container name btw) - especially for a docker-compose config.